# expected type parameter `T`, found `&T`

Tags: generics, rust

I have a generic struct, but I have a problem.

```
#[derive(Debug,Clone,Serialize,Deserialize)]
    pub struct Item<T> {
      pub edges: Option<Vec<T>>
    }
    impl<T> Item<T> {
      pub fn to_result(self) -> Option<T>{
        match self.edges {
          Some(edges) =>{
            if edges.is_empty() { return None; }
            return edges.first();
          },
          None => None
        }
      }
    }
```

I get this error:

```
    expected type parameter `T`, found `&T`

    note: expected enum `std::option::Option<T>`
             found enum `std::option::Option<&T>`
    help: type parameters must be constrained to match other types
    note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#traits-as-parameters
```

The **edges.first()** gets a reference, which causes an error.

please help me.

Comment: Side note: you should probably use a straight `Vec<T>` instead of an `Option<Vec<T>>`, unless it makes sense for your program to differentiate between `None` and an empty `Vec`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are consuming the vector and attempting to send a reference to the first element.

```
pub fn to_result(self) -> Option<T>{
    self.edges?.into_iter().next()
}
```

There is no need to check if contained vector has any elements or not. You can use `into_iter()` to consume the vector and send the first element if available. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dfcb5e5ff1563b9b6c6a8da953a5328e)

To make your code work, you can do the following.

```
impl<T> Item<T> {

    pub fn to_result(self) -> Option<T>{
        match self.edges {
            Some(edges) =>{
                if edges.is_empty() { return None; }
                return edges.into_iter().next();
            },
            None => None
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To make it even more idiomatic you could write `self.values?.into_iter().next()` instead of the `if let`.

Comment: Yes. it is more concise. Let me update it. Keep forgetting about ? usage on Option.